# Как убрать перевод строки после фото?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать пустое место после фото?

```
<img title="Фотографія" src="http://placekitten.com/600/200" />
<div id="about_box">
   <h1 id="title">Текст</h1>
</div>
```

и

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/uStYc/1/).

Comment: Непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

дело в том, что браузер автоматически ставит перенос строки перед и после div

помогают свойства padding и margin

Answer (score 0):

```
<img title="Фотографія" src="http://placekitten.com/600/200" />
<div id="about_box" style="position:relative;top:-6px;">
   <h1 id="title">Текст</h1>
</div>

<img title="Фотографія" src="http://placekitten.com/600/200" / style="position absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;">
<div id="about_box" style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:0px;">
   <h1 id="title">Текст</h1>
</div>

<img title="Фотографія" src="http://placekitten.com/600/200"/>
<div id="about_box">
   <h1 id="title">Текст</h1>
</div>
<style>
*{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Это единственный способ?

Comment: нет но просто кросбраузерный этот а есть меого других способов: использовать margin padding для изображения или абсолютно позиционировать все элементы и т.д таких способов много

Comment: Можно увидеть примеры других способов?

Comment: Вот с вас хватит остальное учите сами!

Comment: Мне бы последний вариант подошел....но он не работает

Comment: Сами учите. Помогает img {display:block;}

Answer (score -1):

чтоб убрать перевод строки:

```
style="display: inline"
```